# I need to truncate all query string p_year_end to 8 characters and/or raise a page not found if the parameter exceeds 8 characters using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to truncate all query string p_year_end to 8 characters and/or raise a page not found if the parameter exceeds 8 characters using mod_rewrite

for example

http://ServerNameABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS:9999/1234/SCHEMA/webleavereq.leave_balances?p_year_end=iMlFsSgMBMYirEErsMqUI

http://ServerNameABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS:9999/1234/SCHEMA/webleavereq.display?p_year_end=RUgtoSimQaIQOrvsS

http://ServerNameABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS:9999/1234/SCHEMA/webleavereq.display?p_year_end=20231231

Also can these rules be within a victual host?

I have tried
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p_year_end=([^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{1,8})/?$ ?p_year_end=$1 [NC,L]

but doesn't appear to work but basically I am  new to this and no idea what I am doing.

It does appear to have any effect at all